# Action Menu on table

Tags: tables, interface, experience

I was recently working on a table project and I came up with an issue.
I have a table where each row has a set of actions as "Add to bookmark" "Add to CRM" "View Full Screen".

So here showing this actions on all the rows all the time doesn't look good.
So what I have done is I have introduced an action menu which comes when you hover over any row. (As shown in image)

But I was not able to achieve the full output.

The problem with this is: User has to hover on each row to know which is bookmarked and which is not.

and in another version, i have made all actions next to the first column and if it is already bookmarked I show it always and if it's not it will be shown on hover.

Let me know if there is a better way to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6):

> So here showing this actions on all the rows all the time doesn't look good.

To solve this, **you need an action bar**. You could have it like how you currently have, which is shown in yellow. Another option is to show the submenu on *more icon* (vertical ellipsis) click.

> User has to hover on each row to know which is bookmarked and which is not.

To solve this, your second screenshot is great.

So basically, I suggest you **combine both the options**.